# How to prove that if $P_{U}T=TP_{U}$, then $U$ and $U^{\perp}$ are both invariant under $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $T \in L(V)$ and that $U$ is a subspace of $V$. I would like to prove that if $P_{U}T=TP_{U}$, then $U$ and $U^{\perp}$ are both invariant under $T$.

I have the first proof that $U$ is invariant under $T$ but cannot get that $U^{\perp}$ is invariant under $T$.

Proof that $U$ is invariant under $T$:

Let $u \in U$, then $Tu=TP_{U}u$=$P_{U}T_{U}u \in U$.

But I dont know how to show that $U^{\perp}$ is invariant under T.

My guess is to use the above given, $P_{U}T=TP_{U}$, but to instead alter it $P_{U^{\perp}}T=TP_{U^{\perp}}$. Is this correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall  that $P_{U^\perp}=I-P_U$. If $T$ commutes with $P_U$, it also commutes with $I-P_U$, so you can swap $U$ and $U^\perp$ in your proof.

Comment: How did u come up with the relation $P_{U^\perp}=I-P_U$? Thanks

Comment: @user What is your definition of $U^\perp$?

Comment: My definition is that it is the orthogonal complement to U, is is such that the full space can be written as U direct sum u perpendicular

Comment: @user Right. You can write every vector $x$ as $x=u+v$ with $u\in U$, $v\in U^\perp$. Here $u=P_Ux$ and $v=P_{U^\perp}x$. So, $P_U+P_{U^\perp}$ is the identity operator.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be delinked from orthogonality or inner products. Let $T,S\in L(V)$ such that $TS=ST$. Then Image of $S$ and Kernel of $S$ are invariant under $T$. Let $v\in \ker S$.  So, $S(v)=0$. Then  $T(S(v))=0$, and  $S(T(v))=0 $,  i.e. $T(v)\in \ker S$.

In your case (we are in a vector space with an inner product),  take $S$ as $P_U$,  the orthogonal projection to a subspace $U$  and $U^\perp = \ker p_U$, so we are done.

More generally let $S$ commute with a collection of endomorphisms $T_1, T_2,\ldots T_m$. i.e. $T_iS= ST_i$. Then image of $S$,  kernel of $S$  both are  invariant under all the $T_i$. For complex vector space any eigenspace of $S$ is also invariant under all the $T_i$'s. This fact leads to  Schur's lemma 
and we get the fundamental result in representation theory of groups, viz. orthogonality of irreducible  characters of a group.